# MongoDb, how to get database from Client object when its name specified in URI?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I initiate my [Express](https://expressjs.com/) app, I define all required parameters in `Environmental Variables`.

According to code [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/tutorials/connect/):

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'myproject';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);

  client.close();
});
```

To get a database object I need:

1. **To pass** database name when I initialize my application. One more `environment variable`, don't like it.
2. **To parse** `URI` object like this: `mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject` to extract database name. One more line of code, don't like it either.

Is there another 3rd solution? When I tried to debug `client` object which returned if connection was successful I've seen that it already contains name of the database connected to *see screenshot below*, but I haven't found any [official API](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/MongoClient.html) how to use it. Use a "hacky" way I don't like too.

[image]

Comment: I fail to see why `I don't like it` is a valid objection. Either way, the API needs a database name, it's just how it works. FWIW, it's more common in practice to provide it as part of the URI in the environment variables and parse it from there than it is to provide it separately.

Comment: The more effort you make to cause something to work (more code, more variables) it's more error-prone, see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHcToNCn4K8

Comment: This is a trivial complication. It's something you need to write once and never have to touch again. It's not like parsing a `dbName` from that URI will ever change.

Answer (score 1):

This is now simply done by simply not passing any variable to `client.db()`.

As documentation states out:

> The name of the database we want to use. If not provided, use database
> name from connection string.

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/MongoClient.html#db